# Python plotting put and call options

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science, finance, numerical-methods, quantitative-finance

I am trying to plot the put/call option using python but I am having some errors when obtaining my values and plot looks weird. I think there is something wrong with my loop of the matrices. My put and call prices should be 0.37 & 1.03. But I just get a printed out matrix. Some help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

S = 8.5 
K = 8
r = 0.02
sigma = 0.2
T = 1
h = 0.0005
N = int(T/h)

stock_price = np.zeros((N+1,N+1))
option_price_call = np.zeros((N+1,N+1))
option_price_put = np.zeros((N+1,N+1))


stock_price[0,0] = S
for j in range(1, N+1):
    stock_price[0,j]= stock_price[0,j-1] *np.exp(sigma*np.sqrt(h)*np.random.normal())

for j in range(0, N+1):
    option_price_call[N,j] = max(stock_price[N,j]-K,0)
    option_price_put[N,j] = max(K-stock_price[N,j],0)
    
for i in range(N-1, -1, -1):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        stock_price[i,j] = stock_price[i+1,j]*np.exp(-r*h)
        option_price_call[i,j] = (option_price_call[i+1,j+1]+option_price_call[i+1,j])/2
        option_price_put[i,j] = (option_price_put[i+1,j+1]+option_price_put[i+1,j])/2
         
print(option_price_call)
print(option_price_put)



plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(stock_price[0,:],option_price_call[0,:], 'r', label = "Call option")
plt.plot(stock_price[0,:],option_price_put[0,:], 'b', label = "Put option")
plt.xlabel("Stock")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn


# Fortis stock price 
spot_price = 138.90

# Long put
strike_price_long_put = 135
premium_long_put = 4

# Long call
strike_price_long_call = 145 
premium_long_call = 3.50

# Stock price range at expiration of the put
sT = np.arange(0.7*spot_price,1.3*spot_price,1)


def call_payoff(sT, strike_price, premium):
   return np.where(sT > strike_price, sT - strike_price, 0) - premium
payoff_long_call = call_payoff(sT, strike_price_long_call, premium_long_call)


# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.plot(sT,payoff_long_call,label='Long Call',color='r')
plt.xlabel('Stock Price')
plt.ylabel('Profit and loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]